# Cant handle UIBarButtonItem events

Tags: iphone, events, uibarbuttonitem

I have a `UIImageView`, which I am adding as the background of a `UIBarButtonItem`. I make the UIBarButtonItem as the right barbuttonitem of my navigation controller. I am not able to handle the `UIBarButtonItem` click event as the control doesn't enter the method, while I am debugging. What could be the reason for this?

```
UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,32,32)];
    [myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]];
    UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myImage];
    //rightBarButton.target = self;
    //rightBarButton.action = @selector(onMyMethod);
    if(isRight){
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton;
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.target = self;
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.action = @selector(onMyMethod);
    }
```

Comment: self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.action = @selector(onMyMethod:);  here the change is I added colon in the selector method

Comment: have you checked the userInteractionEnabled property of UIImageView, that is false by default. You need to set that true.

Comment: @hpiOSCoder I changed that and still it isn't working.

Comment: @RIP I set the userinteractionenabled status to YES and still it isn't working

Comment: @XaviValero- i have updated the post with an answer, you can try if that works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by RIP's answer, I changed the `UIBarButtonItem` and created a `UIButton` instead and added it as subview of the navigationcontroller

```
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"];

        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(onMyMethod:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(260.0, 7.0, 32.0, 32.0);
        button.frame = frame;
        [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:button];
```

Answer (score 2):

I think target and action won't work while using initWithCustomView of UIBarButton, so you can use something like-

```
UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,32,32)];
[myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]];

UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
[rightButton addTarget:self 
                action:@selector(onMyMethod:) 
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];


UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:rightButton];
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit your code:

```
UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,32,32)];
myImage. userInteractionEnabled = Yes;
[myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]];
UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myImage];

if(isRight)
{
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.target = self;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.action = @selector(onMyMethod:);
}
```

Try this Thanks :)

Comment: Its a boolean variable. And the barbuttonitem will be created only if it is true. I tried your piece of code, but it isn't working